# Azure Media Services Locator for YouTube like video publishing

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-media-services

I am creating a site that will have viewing capabilities similar to YouTube.  So far, I am able to upload videos to azure media services but I seem to be confused about how to allow access to the video, to my user base.  I am using javascript chunking and I am generating a write based SAS Url for uploading the video to and this part works.  1) Should I remove the write locator after the file is uploaded to prevent someone else from having write access to the file?  2) It seems like I would want to grant some kind of perpetual access to the video for my usership.  Is there a way to restrict access to only the site domain?  Also, it the locator per user or does it actually expire period once the expiration time is reached?

Comment: Do you have any authentication system(Azure,Google) for your users or any anonymous user can upload and watch video? 1) You need to remove write locator once video has been uploaded.
You can utilize azure media services to dynamically encrypt video and provide users content keys to decrypt stream. You can read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn282272.aspx to see what conent protection options service provide. Based on your scenario and business model you can select PlayReady DRM or AES encryption.

Comment: Users are required to sign up and must be logged in to upload videos.

Comment: Posted answer based on your requirements. There is a small cost associated  with using dynamic encryption (as of now $0.10 / 100 delivered keys) based on information from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on requirements best option will be to utilize AES content protection in Azure Media Services.

1. User sign in with Azure AD or other Identity Provider and navigate to video upload page.
2. System generates SAS locator with write permission for userto upload file to azure storage.
3. Once upload is done user revoke Sas locator and configure dynamic encryption with JWT token based authentication specifying what JWT token claims need to be present in order for other authenticated users to wtch video. You can read how to use Azure AD auth and configure group based permissions in [following blog post](http://www.gtrifonov.com/2015/01/24/mvc-owin-azure-media-services-ad-integration/) . Only authenticated users will be able to watch video and based on identity provider set claims in JWT token you can have other rules. Azure AD supports group claims and https://auth0.com/ supports claims transforamation so you can potentially restrict based on geo location or other rules.